# What does 'friends' mean in the context of Linux package management?

Tags: apt, software-installation, terminology

For example, in the following link:

[NvidiaGraphicsDrivers - Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers#Debian_10_.22Buster.22-1)

it is stated about some apt installation command that "This installs nvcc and **friends**."

What does the word 'friends' mean here? I assume it is something else than just dependencies, otherwise this terminology would probably not exist?

Comment: This question kinda belongs on the ELL SE... :-) In this context, "and friends" just means "et cetera".

Answer (score 3):

There's no technical definition of the term "friends" here. In this context you should interpret it to mean "other related packages".

That definitely includes dependencies.  It may also include "recommend" packages.  Reading the page itself it also includes the *-dev package meaning you get headers to compile against.

Using any technical term casually can lead to confusion.  The word "friends" is used to be deliberately vague, without using a technical term, because the detail is unimportant.

When you go to install with apt, it should give you a list of everything that will be installed if it includes more packages than the ones you explicitly asked for.

Comment: Like I said earlier, it just means "et cetera". Maybe the author could've been less "folksy" and more precise instead of just being vague, but then we're talking about an OS named for some guy and his ex-girlfriend.

Comment: @Rich Et cetera that is used to continue a list. "1, 2, 3, etc." is clearly expanding to 4, 5, 6.   You can't use "1, etc." meaningfully.  Further the definition of "friends" here includes both dependencies and reccomends.  They wouldn't logically be in the same list so no it's not really using the word "friends" to mean et cetera.

Comment: That's kinda embarrassing for you. You wouldn't use "etc" to fill in for a series after giving one example, but in an arbitary list, "et cetera", "and the like", "and others", "and friends", are absolutely the correct meaning here. Source: native English speaker.

Comment: @rich you've missed my point.  "et cetera", "and others", "and friends" have different meanings. They are not interchangable.  Moreover "et cetera" has meaning when attached to a list.  It's meaning is wholly unclear if attached to a single thing.  So "nvcc and friends" has a clear meaning. "nvcc, et cetera" does not.

Comment: No, you're incorrect. In this context, they are in fact interchangeable without changing the intended meaning of the sentence. "nvcc, et cetera" is just as clear, and carries the same exact meaning as "nvcc and friends". Because the payload includes what we could term "a bunch of stuff", and "et cetera" covers the remainder of that bunch, with "nvcc" being one item of stuff. The folksy cadence of "and friends" isn't any different, here.